# What is the meaning of "the principle of the thing"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across this phrase that I don't get the meaning: *the principle of the thing*. Here's the sentence that includes this phrase (a questionnaire item):

> I have, at times stood in the way of people who were trying to do something, not because it amounted to much, but because of **the principle of the thing**.

Comment: Basically the same as doing something [on principle](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=on+principle).

Comment: Arguably the writer wanted to emphasise that there were several different principles involved ("**the** principle" on each different occasion being a "different thing"). But really, it's just that the italicised text is [effectively a cliche](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it's+the+principle%2Cprinciple+of+the+thing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20%27s%20the%20principle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprinciple%20of%20the%20thing%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 7):

I know a guy who went to small claims court to get out of paying a bill he felt he should not have been obligated to pay. He didn't have to pay the $800 bill, but he paid almost $2000 in legal costs.

Some might have viewed that as a net loss, but he considered it a victory, ***because of the principle of the thing***. In other words, he felt it was more important to not pay the bill than to save the money.

Your quote mentions people who "were trying to do something." That's rather vague, but the idea is that, whatever they tried to do, there's a good chance they wouldn't gain anything personally, yet they persevered anyway, because they felt it was the right thing to do.

Comment: That's interesting. You interpret OP's example as meaning *the people the writer obstructed* were trying to do things because they were motivated by principle (they were trying to end war and stuff like that). I just assumed it meant the writer was trying to stop them on principle (he thought they were trying to do bad things). Of course, in the real world, *both* would be motivated by principle (practically everybody is, practically all the time). But people disagree on exactly what "good principles" are, and on how best to put them into practice.

Comment: @Fumble - Yes, true, you could look at it from both sides of the coin. Thanks for a very helpful comment.

Comment: Actually, for our purposes here I suppose it doesn't make any difference which way round you see it. Whenever you read/hear *"the principle of the thing"*, you can safely assume *somebody* feels they're standing on a point of principle (and almost invariably, that there are *others* who don't subscribe to that principle, which is why the stand needs to be taken in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

> I have, at times stood in the way of people who were trying to do something not because it amounted to much, but because of the principle of the thing.

Here, "thing" is quite possibly a reference to the earlier "something".

1. In the past, the writer, more than once witnessed someone doing something.
2. The author believes that this something should be done according to an important rule: a principle, or else not done at all. Or perhaps the author believes in a rule that this something must not be done at all. Either way, this rule is the "principle of that (some)thing".
3. The author stopped the person from doing that something, contrary to to the principle.

The "principle of the thing" could also be using "thing" as a reference to the intangible situation as a whole: the writer stopped people from doing something due to some principle which applied to the situation.

The word "thing", in an intangible sense, is sometimes used vaguely or loosely by English speakers.

A popular introduction for an explanation, concern or complaint is: "Here is the thing, ..." which means something like "I'm about to inform you about some key aspect of some matter".

This doesn't change the interpretation very much. Whether the principle is a rule specifically applying to the thing being done (thing = something), or the overall situation of that other person doing it (thing = situation), basically doesn't matter.

Comment: I agree that, without knowing where this quote came from, it is particularly hard to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

I myself don't entirely understand what the phrase means, but based off of context from when I've heard the phrase, I think it is used for when you are trying to justify something that you've done or something that you want to do, regardless if it is right or wrong.

For example, you are trying to convince your friend to do something, but they aren't really sure it's a good idea, leading you to say, "Come onnnn, its the principle of the thing!" trying to convince them that what you want to do is justified because its whats right, even if its actually wrong.

Comment: Answers should be more than inspired guesses. You should back them up with reputable sources such as dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

First a solid understanding of the word Principle is needed: let's go to http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/principle
: a moral rule or belief that helps you know what is right and wrong and that influences your actions

: a basic truth or theory : an idea that forms the basis of something

: a law or fact of nature that explains how something works or why something happens

My daughter when very young did not understand why I did not move out of someone's way in the aisle of the grocery store.  So I explained, if I am in the aisle of the store looking at a product on the shelf (CustomerA) and CustomerB comes along and stops along the other side of the aisle then, CustomerC comes down the aisle(UNBEKNOWNST to me) and I only become aware of their presence because of their very audible OMG's, huffing, hissing or negative comments.  The Principle is that we are all taught MANNERS, please-thank you- excuse me-pardon me and so on. The thing is a simple "excuse me may I get by you or may I pass" would normally clear the path for CustomerC.  Barney says, Please and Thank you are the Magic Words and they are fundamental/basic rules taught everywhere.

Comment: This doesn't seem to get around to explaining "the principle of the thing", as such, just principles in general.

Answer (score -2):

In other words, *the principle of the thing* is what matters to you. To understand this, you have to ask yourself: Does it matter when it matters? It becomes a principal to me when I value of what it means to me

It's our choice: we choose what's important to us. That is the *principle* way it affects when we say something is *the principle of the thing*.